# Automatic update wordpress DB starting from old version

Tags: database, wordpress, api, updates, auto-update

I'm trying to update an old multisite wordpress instance (3.0.4) to an actual version, passing by 3.1.4, 3.3.3, 3.5.2, 3.7.26 version.
It's possible to update the DB after each step/version without using the browser at all ( maybe using some APIs, curl, etc...) ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use curl or api to upgrade wordpress version but you can do manual update

you can check wordpress codex for more information

[Manual update link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I already know how to update files, I'm just searching for a way to update the **DB** after I already update files (without use the browser)